# incrementing a second variable in a for loop java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that checks if a word is a palindrome or not and my issue is that in my for loop the variable **j** doesn't seem to get any higher than zero even though i am incrementing it (**j++**). Here is my Code(btw I am new to coding so don't be too harsh):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Word");
    String word = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();


    for(int i = word.length(); i>0; i--) {
        int j = 0;

        char modTemp = word.charAt(i-1);
        char wordTemp = word.charAt(j);

        System.out.println("reverse char: "+modTemp);
        System.out.println("Normal char: "+wordTemp);
        System.out.println(j);

        if(modTemp == wordTemp) {
        }

        ++j;

    }

}
```

Comment: Move `int j = 0;` up to before the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed a very beginner mistake...

Comment: We've all been beginners.  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `int j = 0` before the `for` loop. Also nothing stops you to define `for` loop with 2 variables:

```
for (int i = word.length(), j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize you can define two variables in a for  loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Word");
    String word = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = word.length(); i>0; i--) {    
        char modTemp = word.charAt(i-1);
        char wordTemp = word.charAt(j);

        System.out.println("reverse char: "+modTemp);
        System.out.println("Normal char: "+wordTemp);
        System.out.println(j);

        if(modTemp == wordTemp) {
        }

        ++j;

    }

}
```